# Changing the content of the Navigation Drawer on click of button from the fragment, without closing the activity, just reloading it

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I am developing an application where i specifically need to change the navigation drawer Items on user selection.

```
For eg: I have an application which has sports grid view with 6 Different sports to choose from. `1> Cricket 2> Football 3> Baseball 4> Tennis 5> Hockey 6> Basketball.`
When the user selects `Cricket-> i want to change the Navigation items to 
1> Bat 
2>Ball 
3>Pitch info 
4> Rules etc.`

When the user selects `2> Football` the navigation drawer items should change to.

    1> Football info
    2> Rules
    3> Doging tricks etc..
When user selects `3> Baseball` the navigation drawer items should change to 

    1> Baseball info
    2> Baseball bat info
    3> Baseball Player info
    etc
```

Is it possible to do so in android.

Comment: The navigation drawer is basically a fragment, so yes it's possible.

Comment: Can you please help and post any code or any tutorial that does show how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The Navigation Drawer is a fragment with a listview in it. As described here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

So you can just change the array of the list and you are ready to go. (code from the link above)

```
mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

// Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));

Comment: Thanks mate but, how would i show it without reloading the app.

Comment: For example by using a custom adapter and by calling its notifydatasetchanged() method. However I'm not 100% if it'll work...try it out :)

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that I need to change the Sub menus in the Navigation drawer not the main. Something like the Collapsible navigation items of the collapsible items

Comment: I never used submenus in the drawer. But it should be the same as with expendable listviews